# Lightning Input type="text"

Tags: lightning-design-system

I am working on a lightning page where I have to use lightning input type= text. And this value I have to pass JS controller for the validation check. But when I am writing code below it is working fine:

```
<ui:inputText aura:id="fstname" label="First Name"
                              class="slds-input"
                              labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                              value="{!v.newaccount.Name}"
                              required="true"/>`
```

---

```
({
    clickCreateAccount : function(component, event, helper) { 
        var validExpense = true; 
        var accnme = component.find("fstname");
        var aname = accnme.get("v.value");

        if (($A.util.isEmpty(aname))){
            validExpense = false;
            accnme.set("v.errors", [{message:"Name can't be blank."}]);
        }
        else {
            accnme.set("v.errors", null);
        }  
    }
})
```

For the same JS controller once I am writing the code on its throwing error:

```
<lightning:input aura:id="fstname" type="text" label="Account Name" class="slds-input"
                                     value="{!v.newaccount.Name}" required="true"/>
```

error:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
>   Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.set(): 'errors' of component 'markup://lightning:input {18:0} {fstname}' is not visible to 'markup://c:NewAccount_contact {3:0}'.
>   Failing descriptor: {c:NewAccount_contact}

I want to use "lightning:input" as my input text field and set the value to the field. Please help me in this!

Comment: It is wise to enable "debug" mode for issues like this. Will give you better error explanation. - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_debug_mode.htm

What is the access level of attribute "newaccount"?

Comment: <aura:attribute name="newaccount" type= "Account" 
                   default="{'sobjectType': 'Account',
                      'Name': '',  
                      'Phone': ''}"/>

Comment: And what is the access level at component level?

Comment: <aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="Account" type="Account[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="newaccount" type= "Account" 
                   default="{'sobjectType': 'Account',
                      'Name': '',  
                      'Phone': ''}"/>

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is on these lines, where you are setting ***v.errors***:

```
if (($A.util.isEmpty(aname))){
    validExpense = false;
    accnme.set("v.errors", [{message:"Name can't be blank."}]);
} else {
    accnme.set("v.errors", null);
}
```

This will work fine as long as you use `ui:inputText` as this component supports `errors` attribute, which you can set from client side controller. Refer more on attributes supported by this component on its documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputText.htm).

When you change your code to `lightning:input`, this component **does not support** `errors` attribute. And that is what the error message is complaining about:

> *'**errors**' of component 'markup://**lightning:input** {18:0} {fstname}' is **not visible***

You will need to handle the error messaging on the component using what is available or by writing some additional validations in your JS controller. Below is a snippet from the documentation for `lightning:input`, you can refer more on its documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm).

> **Input Validation**
>
> Client-side input validation is available for this component. For
>   example, an error message is displayed when a URL or email address is
>   expected for an input type of url or email.

Answer (score 0):

A component not having `access` system attribute may return undefined or cause access violation issues. In your case, adding access attribute like this - `<aura:component access="public">` should solve the issue. Let me know if this works out.

Edit:
As mentioned by jayant, accessing an  unavailable attribute also causes access check failure. Sorry, I forgot to write about this.